# data extraction in C++

Tags: c++

Hello all I am reading from a data file using the code

```
//................  
//...................  
char databuff[20];  
char ch;  
for(int i=0;i<15;i++)  {  
    f[0].getline(databuff,((2*sizeof(double))+(2*sizeof(char))));  
    //...............  
    //...............
    cDisp=databuff;  
    cDisp1+=cDisp;  
    cDisp1+="\r\n";  
}  
GetDlgItem(IDC_DISPLAYFILE)->SetWindowTextW(cDisp1);
```

Now the data seems to be two double floats separated by `","`
How can I extract the two double values in two different double variables from the databuff I have used in the code? The output of the program is like below....
0,334.152
0.0133333,334.152
0.0266667,334.143
0.04,334.143
0.0533333,334.134
0.0666667,334.125
0.08,334.125
0.0933333,334.125
0.106667,334.116
0.12,334.116
0.133333,334.116
0.146667,334.116
0.16,334.125
0.173333,334.134
0.186667,334.431

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a strstream on top of your databuff and just read using `double d0, d1; char t; str >> d0 >> t >> d1;`

Alternatively, you could try `strchr` to locate the ',', then use `atof` on the two substrings (or std::find if you want the C++ way.)

Comment: can you please suggest me how to use the strchr on the databuff?

Comment: the output of my program is like   0,334.152